# kendo UI grid dataitem set method

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
grid.dataItem(selectedRow)
```

this is return the selected row which is a kendo.data.ObservableObject.

this object has all the columns for that grid's selected row. Is there a way to iterate thru all the columns and update. 
or do i have to do it like this:

```
dataitem.set("Id", 1);
dataitem.set("name", Eric);
dataitem.set("age", 12);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I understand what you are trying is to copy one JavaScript object into a Grid item, correct?

Let's assume that you have the new value in `val`:

```
var val = {
    Id : 1,
    name: "Eric",
    age: 12
};
```

And you want to copy it in the selected row.

There are several ways of doing it:

1. What you just did.
2. Iterate through the different keys of `val` and copy the value.
3. Use jQuery extend.

Option 2.

```
for (var key in val) {
    if (val.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        dataitem.set(key, val[key]);
    }
}
```

Option 3.

```
$.extend(item, val);
item.set("uid", kendo.guid());
```

The first instruction performs a deep copy of `val` into `item`.
The second instruction makes the item `dirty` by just changing the UID.

**NOTE:** You don't need to update every single field using `set`, is enough changing one and all will get updated.

Comment: setting the uid to a new value is triggering the on data bound event for me, is this normal?